# Two different Autodesk Forge apps are running same code

Tags: autodesk-forge

Please, it looks to me that I am asking a very basic question; however I could not find an explanation yet. I used .NET and both exercises for view models and modify models work great individually. I mean that I found no problems testing view models when this one was the only example available or modifying models when this one was the only example available. However, when both examples are available, doesn't matter which was the example selected and executed from inside Visual Studio that always goes to modifying models. Please notice that I created two different apps (obviously with different ClientId and secret key). Maybe not quite a good understanding of Autodesk Forge apps? Any help to understand what is going on?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If the two projects are in one solution you can specify which one to run as the default project as well as several projects at once and their order - see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/05/09/choosing-the-startup-project/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2019)...

Looks like this is rather a question on VS than Forge so I'd suggest to remove the `autodesk-forge` tag...